# Compare two dates with specific date

Tags: javascript, html

this was mine third school assignment

Write a JavaScript function that compares two dates. Call this function compare_date () and give this function two input parameters. Take off the code below and make sure the window.alert () returns a message or date one is greater or less than 2 date or perhaps date 1 equals 2 date

i got something like this

```
var d1 = new Date(2017, 0, 2); // 2 januari 2017 
var d2 = new Date(2017, 0, 1); // 1 januari 2017

window.alert(compare_date(d1,d2));


function compare_date(date1,date2){  


}
```

Comment: Asking assignment question is not wrong but try something first; empty function really ?

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: @Dimitri Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: my question i have no idea how to do this... can someone help me

Comment: note: `/* anything involving '=' should use the '+' prefix
 it will then compare the dates' millisecond values*/
+x <= +y;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
var d1 = new Date(2017, 0, 2); // 2 januari 2017 
var d2 = new Date(2017, 0, 1); // 1 januari 2017

compare_date(d1,d2);
    
function compare_date(date1,date2){  
   if (date1 > date2) {
        alert("Date One is greather than Date Two.");
   }else if (date2 > date1) {
        alert("Date Two is greather than Date One.");
   }else{
       alert("Both are equal.");
   }
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3DKfy/103/)

Comment: Thans this was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below one which is just a simple one like `date1 > date2`.

**Note**: `date1 > date2` and `date1.getTime() > date2.getTime()` are same.

```js
var d1 = new Date(2017, 0, 2); // 2 januari 2017 
var d2 = new Date(2017, 0, 1); // 1 januari 2017

window.alert(compare_date(d1,d2));


function compare_date(date1, date2){  
 return (date1.getTime() === date2.getTime() ? 'Equal' : (date1 > date2 ? 'date1 is greater than date 2' : 'date1 is less than date2'));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```js
var d1 = new Date(2017, 0, 2); // 2 januari 2017 
var d2 = new Date(2017, 0, 1); // 1 januari 2017

window.alert(compare_date(d1,d2));


function compare_date(date1,date2){  
  var diff = date1 - date2;
 if (diff < 0)
   return "date 2 is bigger";
  else
  if (diff > 0)
   return "date 1 is bigger";
  else
  return "are the same"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT : Math.sign() is Ecmascript 2015**

make a reusable function:

return 0 if dates are equal

return -1 if d1 is before d2

return 1 if d1 is after d2

```js
var d1 = new Date(2017, 0, 2); // 2 januari 2017
var d2 = new Date(2017, 0, 1); // 1 januari 2017

window.alert(compare_date(d1,d2));


function compare_date(date1, date2){  
    return Math.sign(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
}
```